# SQL Procedure error in printing statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
Delimiter $$;
create procedure greetings()
dbms_output.put_line('Hello'); $$
```

This gives the following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.put_line('Hello')' at line 1

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not provide `dbms_output.put_line()`.

Instead of that you can simply try below code in your procedure.

```
SELECT 'Hello';
```

Comment: Yep this worked, but when I execute it it gives the following error :Unknown prepared statement handler (greet) given to EXECUTE

Comment: `call greetings()` You have to try only this much of code.